# Как уменьшить размер образа Docker

Tags: изображения, docker

Работаю с докером на винде. Скачал себе образ Debian, создал контейнер и начал его изменять под свои нужды. Периодически делаю `docker commit webserver_debian10 webserver_debian10 webserver:my` и затем `docker save -o d:\webserver_debian10.tar webserver_debian10`. И вот сейчас увидел, что конечный файл-файл стал просто огромным, аж 6.7гб, внутри куча слоев. Кошмарный кошмар. Подскажите пожалуйста, как или очистить этот образ от ненужного, или как то пересоздать новый? Я что то не могу разобраться, пробовал `docker system prune -a` но это видимо не то.

Спасибо!

Comment: можно погуглить про squash образов, там есть отдельные команды и тулы для этого, но я ничем из этого не пользовался, может вам подойдет

Comment: посмотрел - какой то ад, ничего не понял... нахрена делать софтвар с подобной задумкой и настолько убого реализовать важнейшую составляющую идеи - переносимость и сохранение изменений. люди смотрю, много кто с этим вопросом бегает, вменяемой ясной мысли про решение проблемы размера образов не увидел нигде. но спасибо за ответ

Comment: У тебя случайно в образ не архивируется все логи? Логи внутри докера не надо хранить никогда. Вот тут в статье есть пример, как логи Nginx перенаправляются на файловую систему хоста https://medium.com/interleap/docker-volumes-and-logging-a839011950f7 `docker container run -p 8180:80 -d -v /var/log/serverlogs:/var/log/nginx nginx`

Comment: Кроме логов веб сервера могут сохранять какие-то промежуточные состояния в `/tmp`. Это всё надо или чистить внутри запущенного контейнера периодически или тоже перенаправлять как и логи.

Comment: Для начала стоить зайти внутрь контейнера `docker exec -i CONTAINER bash` и посмотреть, куда сколько места ушло с помощью команды `du -sh *` и если потребуется, заходить внутрь больших папок и там выполнять опять

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Плюнул на Докер, гори он в аду, развернул ВиртуалБокс, все вменяемо, ясно и предсказуемо. Спасибо.